# Can't pass id to nested route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

For a personal achievment, I'm trying to create an online magazine to let people read some news

I created two scaffolds, one for the manga and the other for its pages. I manage to create the magazine, upload its pages via a multi upload system thanks to the second scaffold.

Then, I wanted the link for a magazine's page to look like `domain.net/magazines/:id/pages/:id`, however, I'm getting some difficulties that I don't seem to be able to solve by myself

Here's my magazines#show view:

```
<h4>
  <%= @magazine.titre %>
</h4>

  <%= image_tag @magazine.apercu, size: '200x200' %>

<% @magazine.pages.each do |m| %>
    <%= link_to magazine_page_url, :id => m.id do %> <!-- Here -->
      <%= image_tag m.image, size: '100x100' %>
    <% end %>

    <%= link_to m do %>
        <%= image_tag p.image, size: '100x100' %>
    <% end %>

    <%= link_to 'Supprimer', m, :method => :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
<% end %>

<br />

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_magazine_path(@magazine) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', magazines_path %>
```

Whenever I try to get this page, I'm getting the following error:

**ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Magazines#show -- No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"pages", :id=>"6"} missing required keys: [:magazine_id]**

As you can see, I'm trying to create a link around every magazine's pages to redirect to the pages itself, but I can't manage to give a proper id to the link.

When I try to put `<%= link_to m do %>` instead of `magazine_page_url`, he's searching for a path named 'page_path', that doesn't exist since I nested the page resources inside my magazines resources.

Here is my route file just in case, don't hesitate if you need to see something else

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root to: 'home#index'

  namespace :admin do
    resources :carousels
  end
  get '/admin' => 'admin#index', as: :admin_root

  resources :magazines do
    resources :pages
  end

end
```

Any help is welcome

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass magazine and page instances into url params:

```
<%= link_to magazine_page_url(@magazine, m) do
```

Too you can do:

```
<%= link_to [@magazine, m] do
```

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm, plus I didn't think at all about this possibility !